# Force Java MimeUtility.encodeWord to always encode

Tags: java, email-headers

```
  String encodedString = MimeUtility.encodeWord(myString, "utf-8", "Q");
```

The MimeUtility.encodeWord only encodes if a non US-ASCII character is found. For best use in a email header i want to always encode like this.

So is it a way to force it to encode a string?